# Bash script how to extract the status code and a particular header value in two variables in one curl call

Tags: bash, unix, sh

Say I am making a curl request:  curl -X HEAD https://example.org -i

i want HTTP Response Code and a header field 'expires' in two different variables without making http request multiple times in my shell script.

Something like this i am currently doing,

`url = " -X HEAD https://example.org -i "`

`` httpCode = `eval curl --write-out '%{http_code} ${url}` ``

`` expiresHeader = `eval curl ${url} | grep expires` ``

I want to make only one http request and still be able to get the two fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can keep the whole response head (status line and headers) in a variable and then "select" only the things you want. for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

url="https://example.org"

resp=`curl -s --head -i "$url"`
httpCode=`echo "$resp" | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
expiresHeader=`echo "$resp" | grep "expires"`

echo "$httpCode"
echo "$expiresHeader"
```

---

```
$ bash script
200
expires: Mon, 28 Sep 2020 17:48:41 GMT
$
```

Comment: It works for me. I was missing 'echo' before running grep on the variable holding the response. Thanks.

Comment: @JetinderRathore glad I helped you! if it fixed your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer :)